# PhpStorm file type association conflicts for *.ts

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, typoscript, file-type

I have a project (Typo3) which uses Typ**o**script and Typ**e**Script. Both filetypes use the same suffix **`*.ts`** by default. Since I use external libraries I cannot change the suffixes to an alternative.

I know how to change the default file type association or register new ones in JetBrains products. But in that special case I need to you have both file types living side by side.

Is there any chance to scope the file type recognition by regex?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any chance to scope the file type recognition by regex?

Not possible. Such recognition is all based on file name patterns which are IDE-wide (not even project-specific).

---

Unfortunately I could not find exact ticket (if it even exists...  as it was suggested to create such ticket [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10759#comment=27-1011290)).

The best tickets I could quickly find that I think are related:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113835
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-103297
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-77805

Watch those and related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

The best I can offer in your situation (where you cannot change extension; to avoid lots of red warnings for one of the types) is to exclude folder(s) with such files from the project (Mark it as Excluded) or mark individual files as Plain Text so they are not get indexed by incorrect parser. Then you may use some another editor to edit such files...

**P.S.** Maybe you can use double extension for one of the types? For example `*.ts.ts` or `*.typo.ts` is more precise than `*.ts` so will allow them for both to co-exist.

Comment: Thanks for the related links. Good to know  i'm not the only one having this problem. Excluding the related files from indexing doesn't solve the problem in my case. The intention of my questions is, to have the codecompletion in both file types. Sure, I could register alternative files extensions, but this prevents codecompletion for statements defined in external files which I want to override in my code.

Answer (score 1):

It's not final but there was a voting between core devs to change the file extension for typoscript core files and the majority was for `.typoscript` and `.tsconfig`.
`.ts` never was an official file extension for typoscript, the core used `.txt'.

Even if the core will use these file extensions it will be possible to use any file extension for your own usage.
So the easiest way to avoid the conflicting `.ts` for your files is to use something unique identifiable. For some projects I have seen the usage of `.t3s` which some people avoid as there is no origin for the `3` in "typoscript".
`.typoscript`and `.tsconfig` look like matching candidates.

Comment: Using another editor would break my workflow and is therefore no option. Changing the file extensions is no option too as i stated in my previous comment. Seems that we have to wait for planed changes in Typo3 or a new feature in PhpStorm.

Comment: you do not need another editor. if you register these new extensions for the filetype `typoscript` everything is working like before: syntaxhighlightning and codecompletion (at least for my phpstorm 2016.3.2)

Comment: Yes I know, but I cannot rename the file extensions of existing typo extensions. So if register different file extension for typescript the code completion won't work. Example: in my own whatever.typoscript file I want to modify some plugin code, eg the code from the "news" extension. The syntax highlighting works of course, but the codecompletion for the news is broken because it uses the ts file extensions. You see what I mean?

Comment: as long as not all typoscript files have the 'new' extension (especially those from extensions) you need either both extensions configured (with the dilemma of ununique *.ts) or you miss the files still ending in `.ts`. choose the lesser evil. But you also could contact the extension authors and request a rename.